# Running Docker from Visual Studio 2019 on Windows causes a UnauthorizedAccessException to /app/appsettings.json when files are Read-Only due to TFS

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, tfs

i'm building an asp.net project in docker under windows 10 - Linux Container and i'm experiencing a strange problem.
On TFS (MS legacy Source Control ;-) ), all files are read-only unless you check them out. Everything seemed to be working but i guess that the latest updates (Don't know if from docker or visual studio) seem to be causing a file rights problem.

What happens:
1 - if i check everything out and run the asp.net app everything is ok. (All files are writable under windows)

2 - if everything is checked in, and therefore read only, i get a:

```
{System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/app/appsettings.json' is denied.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Operation not permitted
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
   at System.IO.FileStream.OpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.PhysicalFileInfo.CreateReadStream()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at MyShared.Modules.Sample.AspCoreSample.Program.Main(String[] args) in W:\MyShared\Modules.Sample\Trunk\src\Cpoe.AspCoreSample\Program.cs:line 13}
```

Checking with docker.

2. When it does not work 555:

```
root@26d788df21ac:/app# ls -l
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root  192 Mar 19 07:49 appsettings.json
```

1. When it works 755:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  192 Mar 19 07:49 appsettings.json
```

Well, I've tried to RUN a chmod on the dockerfile with no success. 
Also running chown did not help at all. (see 'code' at the end)

I've then decided to copy my sources to a separate folder first, before generating the docker image.
So, I've added a pre-build task:

```
  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="(robocopy $(SolutionDir)Cpoe.AspCoreSample $(SolutionDir)DockerTemp\Cpoe.AspCoreSample /Z /S /A-:R /copy:DT /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS /nc /ns /np) ^&amp; IF %2525ERRORLEVEL%2525 LSS 8 SET ERRORLEVEL = 0" />
    <Exec Command="attrib -r $(SolutionDir)DockerTemp\Cpoe.AspCoreSample\*.* /s" />
  </Target>
```

NOTE: *(robocopy somehow still copies the readonly attribute - but this is another question so that's why i run attrib)*

Everything is well. The read-only attributes are gone.

I then tried create the docker image using this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerTemp/Cpoe.AspCoreSample/MyShared.Shared.Modules.Cpoe.AspCoreSample.csproj", "Cpoe.AspCoreSample/"]
COPY ["DockerTemp/Cpoe.Contracts/MyShared.Shared.Modules.Cpoe.Contracts.csproj", "Cpoe.Contracts/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Cpoe.AspCoreSample/MyShared.Shared.Modules.Cpoe.AspCoreSample.csproj" && \
    dotnet restore "Cpoe.Contracts/MyShared.Shared.Modules.Cpoe.Contracts.csproj"
COPY DockerTemp .
WORKDIR "/src/Cpoe.AspCoreSample"
RUN dotnet build "MyShared.Shared.Modules.Cpoe.AspCoreSample.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyShared.Shared.Modules.Cpoe.AspCoreSample.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyShared.Shared.Modules.Cpoe.AspCoreSample.dll"]
```

And still no 755 on the files! I thought, WHAT!?
I've no other idea.

The updates that might caused it:

- Visual Studio 16.4.6 (I'm always using the latest)
- Docker Engine v19.03.8

I'm running Windows 10 PRO 64 B.18362 WSL 1!!
I hope these kind of problems will be fixed on WSL2 but i can't get Windows Previews on my company for now.

Is there something i'm missing here?

Just for the completeness, this is how I've tried to fix the problem using the docker file, with no success:

```
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data --from=publish /app/publish .
RUN chmod -R 777 /app/data
USER www-data (also tried with 33)
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyShared.Shared.Modules.Cpoe.AspCoreSample.dll"]
```

What do work is connecting to the image, changing the permissions, and running again.
No idea why it requires write rights on these files.

You can see that it really has to do with the read-only flags in Windows, this file has 755:

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  391 Feb 10 18:13 MyShared.Shared.Modules.Cpoe.AspCoreSample.csproj.user

Cheers,
Marco

Comment: If it's the read-only bit that's causing this, try switching to a Local workspace. That doesn't depend on the read-only bit for status. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=azure-devops

Comment: Yes, this would solve it. But then i need to have local workspaces for all my branches... i just want to understand why this is happening. Perhaps i should post in github as a Bug.